# How to make the footer stick to the bottom and stretch the body content from header to footer

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have the following ASP.net code:

```
<div class="pageContent">
    <div style="width: 85%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="headerContent brClear">
            ZSasdasdassad
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent brClear">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="footerContent brClear">
            asdasdads
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pageContent
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.brClear
{
    clear: both;
}
.headerContent
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 165px;
    background: #ffd800;
}
.bodyContent
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background: #f00
}
.footerContent
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ffd800;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Displays at 100%:

[image]

Displays at 70%:

[image]

How do I modify the CSS so that:

1. The red body content stretches from the end of the top yellow header
   all the way to the bottom of the page with a padding-bottom the size of the
   footer so nothing is blocked?
2. The bottom yellow footer stick to the bottom but not stretch to the
   entire page but stay within the parent's DIV width which is 85%?

Comment: i think this can be helpful http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't do what I want. The footer is not all the way at the bottom of the page :/

Comment: you want to have that footer always visible on the screen?

Comment: Yes, please. I would like that

Answer (score 1):

Set `width: auto;` and `height: auto,` in `.pageContent` and get rid of `position: fixed;` in the footer: http://jsfiddle.net/vdcmgune/

Comment: Nothing in the jsfiddle :/

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/kmLb2dgj/

**UPDATE: this is probably the best solution you can get only with css/html**

http://jsfiddle.net/kmLb2dgj/2/

Comment: Something similar... Except, the red content should give the body a scrollbar if it goes beyond but as you scroll all the way to the bottom the padding-below for the red part should be the height for the footer.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: so you want to have dynamic height of footer and give scrollbar to the body instead to the red element. I think this can't be accomplished without javascript. It is ok with pure css/html if you have fixed height of footer.

Comment: Ohhhh I see and thank you for the feedback! I think I will go with your option @Krab :) But have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: I have this: `<asp:HyperLink CssClass="topLogo" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="topLogo">WMG</asp:HyperLink>` and the following CSS: `.topLogo
{
    display: block;
    text-indent: -999em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
    direction: ltr;
}
#topLogo
{
    width: 322px;
    height: 68px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    background: url(theImages/wmlogo.png) no-repeat;
}` but I don't see the image

Answer (score -1):

Take look at this jQuery Sticky Footer. It is a simple solution that works well. (good if you are not using a Bootstrap)

```
function ResizeContent() {

    //Height of the available content area is  Page Height - (Header and Footer height.
    //In this case 100px;
    var ContentHeight = Math.round($(window).height() - 100);
    ContentHeight = ContentHeight + "px";

    $("#MainContainer").css("min-height", ContentHeight);
};


$(function () {
    //Resize the content after page load or resize
     ResizeContent();

    window.onresize = function () {
            ResizeContent();
      };
 });


<div id="MainContainer" style="width:100%;">
    <div  class="panel panel-default" style="width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:20px;">
       <div class="panel-heading">jQuery Sticky Footer</div>
           <div class="panel-body" style="text-align:center">
           jQuery to adjust the content area after the page loads, or resized
           <br /> <br />
           Try resizing this page and see the content  under this panel retain the same areas
           <br /> <br />       
         </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="Footer" style="background-color:#8A898A;color:#ffffff;width:100%;height:60px;text-align:center;padding:20px;">
    This is a sticky footer - <a style="color:white" href="http://www.surfthru.com">www.surfthru.com</a>
</div>
```

http://snippets.surfthru.com/html/JQStickyFooter.html